# How many numbers have $k$ divisors?

Tags: number-theory

I know of the divisor function that gives the number of divisors of $n$. But is there a way to find or approximate the inverse of sorts, i.e., is there a function $D(N,k)$ equal to how many numbers $n<N$ exist such that $\sigma_0(n)=k$. I have no clue where to start for something like that, and haven't found much by searching around. Is this a thing, and if not what work has gone into similar problems?

Comment: The special case where $k=1$, there is the famous Prime Number Theorem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem

Comment: $D(N,1)=1$, $D(N,2),=\pi(N-1)$, $D(N,3)=\pi(\lfloor{\sqrt{N-1}}\rfloor)$.